# module "QtMultimediaKit" is not installed

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Установлен Qt Creator 2.5.2 и Qt 4.8.2 (32 bit)

Запускаю приложение и появляется ошибка:

> module "QtMultimediaKit" is not installed

Модуль нужен для воспроизведения звука.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в `pro файл`:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
```

**UPDATE.**

Попробуйте добавить `viewer.engine()->addImportPath(QString("/opt/qtm12/imports"));` перед установкой qml файла:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.engine()->addImportPath(QString("/opt/qtm12/imports"));
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.showMaximized();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: 1) main.cpp:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QDeclarativeEngine'


2) c:\Qt\4.8.4\src\declarative\qml\qdeclarativecontext.h:58: error: forward declaration of 'struct QDeclarativeEngine'

Вот такие ошибки появляются

Comment: Еще можно использовать Qt5 -- у него уже в корочке есть модуль [мультимедии](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html#details). Для Qt4, как я понимаю, нужно отдельно устанавливать

Comment: Очень нужно в Qt 4